# JFileChooser Buttons CustomisationsGradient Paint for OptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

JFileChooser Buttons CustomisationsGradient Paint for OptionPane

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of you names are correct and others are not. Be consistent! `What can i do for OptionPane?` - nothing. It uses its own components and layout manager to display the components and you don't have access to its content pane. So you just need to customize a JDialog to do the functionality of the option pane.

Comment: Thank you so much Camickr! I will definitely take care of the variable names., How can i customize a J Dialog to do functionality of optionPane?

Comment: A JDialog is just like a JFrame. You can add any components you want to the dialog. So you have to add your own "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons. If you want an Icon then you need to add a JLabel with the Icon etc. Then you have full control over the layout of the components you add to the dialog.

Comment: Thank you so much camickr. :)  I am going to try it.

Comment: You may be able to apply the same concept for the background gradient that solved your problem when using the JFileChooser. The difereence is that when you create the option pane manually the code to use the option pane is more complicated. Read the `JOptionPane` API. The is a section on `Direct Use` that shows you how to manually a JOptionPane. You will then need to decide if using the option pane manually or creating your own custom dialog is easier.